# Precedence of basic mathematical operators

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
int a = 100,b = 3,c = 8,d = 6;
System.out.println(a - d * b + c);
```

Answer is 90.

how is that calculation done?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. This is just the order of precedence of basic mathematical operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: wikipedia...always a several page answer to a 1 sentence question.  Peter's link is the much easier read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BODMAS** rule is used to evaluate the expression .

1. d*b = 18
2. "+" and "-" have same precedence . But "-" comes first in the left. 
   SO 100 - 18 = 82
3. And then 82 + 8 = 90.

Answer (score 2):

`*` has higher precedence so multiplication will be evaluated first

so

`6*3` will get evaluated first

100- 18 + 8 = 90

**See**

- [Operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
a - (d * b) + c 
100 - 18 + 8 = 90
```

Answer (score 1):

This is maths in the first classes.

`*` before `+`

So it's `6 * 3` in the first step, afterwards it's `100 - 18 + 8 = 90`.

Answer (score 1):

- Multiply and Divide - Treated equally, but have priority over
  Addition and Subtraction
- Add and Subtract - Treated equally but    have a lower priority than
  multiplication and division

Follow the above rules we first Multiply then add/sub.So result is 90.

Answer (score 0):

```
a - (d * b) + c
= 100 - (6 * 3) + 8
= 100 - 18 + 8
= 100 - 10
= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

```
100-6*3+8 = 100-18+8 = 100-10 = 90
```

or what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `*` has higher precedence. So,

```
a - 6 * 3 + c => a - 18 + c
```

**2.** `+` has higher precedence then `-`. So,

```
a - 18 + 8 =>  a - 10
```

**3.** And at the end.

```
100 - 10  => 90
```

So output should be 90.